# How to run react-native for windows? I have a problem: npx react-native run-android error

Tags: javascript, node.js, android-studio, react-native

I want to run the React Native project. I tried this command already; npx react-native run-android and. I tried to solve all the errors but still can't run the project. Here's the error output.

> ```
> PS C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp> npx react-native run-android
> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
> Jetifier found 903 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
> info Starting JS server...
> info Launching emulator...
> info Successfully launched emulator.
> info Installing the app...
> :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
> :ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * Where:
> Script 'C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 205
>
> * What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
>   throw err;
>   ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)  
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
>     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requireStack: []}
>
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
> :ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
> :ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Script 'C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 205
>
> * What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
>   throw err;
>   ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
>     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  requi
> * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 3s
>
>     at makeError (C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
>     at C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
>     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
>     at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
>     at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
> info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> ```

Comment: I just *guessed* at useful message layout - please check an don't hesitate to start over with a fresh copy&paste between code fences (lines with just `~~~`).

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and I noticed what were common in our errors was the fact that:

- There's **UTF-8 characters**: `ü` in the path where the project is.
  `C:\Users\batuh\OneDrive\Masaüstü\native\androidApp>`

Which means it does not have the utf-8 encoding somewhere along the building process.

---

Solution: Move your project to a path ***without*** those characters